# Name of a matrix with one column and row removed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education

I am looking for the exact name of a matrix where the i-th column and rows have been removed.

I cannot remember how it is named in linear algebra, does anyone got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Cofactor matrix of $a_{i,i}$.

Comment: That is what I was trying to remember, thanks!

Comment: @xbh: if you put your comment in an answer, I will validate it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the **cofactor matrix** of $a_{j,j}$. "Cofactor" refers to the result after deletion, and itself is used to refer to the determinant. Cofactor matrix is a derived name from that.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [submatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix) (or possibly *principal submatrix*)? Or you might be thinking of the [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)), which is the determinant of the thing you are describing, although it doesn't assume that the same-indexed row and column were removed.

Comment: Yes I would call it a principal submatrix, "principal" meaning that the set of indices of deleted rows is the same as the set of indices of deleted columns.

Answer (score 1):

you might be referring to:

1. Submatrix
2. the minor - [wikipedia - Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra))
3. a matrix shape resulting from a Gaussian elimination   [Reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the determinant, the term is minor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)

Answer (score 0):

A matrix with certain rows and columns removed is called submatrix

https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node10.html